# How to set vertical and horizontal bar in div?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have a following code in which I have to set vertical bar.

Is there anyway to put vertical bar in div?

Following code is for dashboard so I need small vertical line so that it doesn't look clumsy.

How to set vertical and horizontal bar in div?

```
 <div class="box box-primary">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
          <h3 class="box-title">Work Anniversary</h3>
          <div class="box-tools pull-right">
            <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
            <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.box-header -->
        <div class="box-body">
          <ul class="products-list product-list-in-box">


              <% date = Date.today %>
             <% @employees = JoiningDetail.where("DATE_FORMAT(joining_date,'%d/%m') = ?", date.strftime('%d/%m'))%>
            <% if @employees.empty? %>

            <%else%>
              <% @employees.each do |e| %>
                <li class="item"> 
                  <div class="product-img">
                  <%unless e.nil? or e.nil? or  e.employee.member.nil? or e.employee.member.avatar.nil? %>
                 <% if e.employee.gender == "Male" && e.employee.member.avatar_file_name == nil  %>
                 <%= image_tag "avatar5.png",class: "img-circle", alt: "User Image", size: "25x25" %>
                  <% elsif e.employee.gender == "Female" && e.employee.member.avatar_file_name == nil  %>
                  <%= image_tag "avatar2.png",class: "img-circle", alt: "User Image", size: "25x25" %>
                   <%else%>
                   <%= image_tag e.employee.member.avatar.url(:medium),class: "img-circle"%>
                  <%end%> <!-- if -->
                   <%end%> <!-- unless -->
                </div> 
                <div class="product-info">
                  <%= full_name(e.employee) %>
                <div class="pull-right">
                <% @greeting = Greeting.where(sender_id: current_user.employee_id,date: Date.today,receiver_id: e.employee_id,greeting_type: "Anniversary") %>
                  <% if e.employee_id == current_user.employee_id %>
                      <small class="label label-success">Wish You A Very Happy Work Anniversary!</small>
                  <% else %>
                    <% if @greeting.empty? %>
                        <%= link_to 'Wish', anniversary_mail_greetings_path(emp_id: e.employee_id),class: 'btn btn-xs btn-primary',remote:true %>
                    <% else %>
                        <small class="label label-success">Message Sent</small>
                    <% end %>
                  <% end %>
                </div>
                  <span class="users-list-date"><%= e.employee.department.try(:name) %></span>
                  </div>

                <% end %> <!-- do -->
            </li><!-- /.item -->
            <%end%> <!-- if employee.empty? -->
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: inside your code in which part you want to show vertical line ?

Answer (score 0):

> Put a < div> tag where you want to display vertical line and use below mentioned CSS

```
.verticalLine {
  border-left: thick solid #ff0000;
}

<div class="verticalLine">
  keep your content here
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to get vertical bars in a div, but you will have to choose the implementation below that fits what you're looking for best.

**Border**

If you need a vertical line that spans the full height of your div and you have no concerns about needing a margin, a CSS border could do the trick.

```
border-left: 1px solid black;
```

will render a black thin line on the left side of the div.

**Separator: Pseudo Element**

If you are looking for a vertical separator between divs that needs its own margins, height, or other styles, consider a pseudo element. Whichever div you wish to have the vertical bar in you can use pure CSS to create a pseudo element before or after the div's content.

```
.div-class:after{ content: "|"; }
```

Of course you can style that pseudo element to look however you want - use a border or background instead of a character if you want it to stretch.